# How to log the body from every request in Play?

Tags: scala, playframework

Is there a way to log the body of a request in play framework (2.3.x)? I think that I'm on the right way with [Filters](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaHttpFilters), but I don't know how to access the body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filters only have access to the RequestHeader. At this point, the body of the request has not been processed.
Because Play Framework is reactive, a filter can act as soon as the request header is received, and does not need to wait for the whole body to have been consumed (what can take a large amount of time if the body is large, and/or the browser is sending it very slowly)

If you want to log the request body, you should have a look to [ActionBuilder](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaActionsComposition).
ActionBuilder receive a Request, that is the request header and the body.

At that place, you can log the body.

Comment: +1, use an ActionBuilder to create a LogAction that logs the body and use that instead of Action.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to execute code after `block(request)` in the first code snippet from the ActionBuilder documentation?

Comment: @TWdorado yes, `block(request)` delivers a Future. For example: `block(request).map { r => Logger.debug("end"); r }`

Comment: This would only work for existing routes though, it won't be able to log calls to a wrong route.