# Java Play: Using an EssentialAction in an EssentialFilter to access the body of a request?

Tags: java, playframework

I'm currently trying to find a way to use a filter to catch all inbound requests and then send the body off somewhere else, per the officaldocumentation here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaHttpFilters this should be possible as the last section states:
"Play provides a lower level filter API called EssentialFilter that gives you full access to the body of the request. This API allows you to wrap EssentialAction with another action."

However, when I create an EssentialAction wrapped in my EssentialFilter I'm only given access to the header of the request and the example listed doesn't really cover how to access the body.

This makes sense per this accepted answer: [How to log the body from every request in Play?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25492592/how-to-log-the-body-from-every-request-in-play), but is in conflict with what the official docs state.

Is there something I'm missing?

```java
public class SendBodyFilter extends EssentialFilter {
    private final Materializer mat;
    
    @Inject
    SendBodyFilter(
            Materializer mat
    ) {
        super();
        this.mat = mat;
    }
    @Override
    public EssentialAction apply(EssentialAction next) {
        return EssentialAction.of(request -> {
            System.out.println(request);
            return next.apply(request);
        });
    }
}
```